# CSS блоки нестандартной формы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, layout, clip-path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстаю уже давно, но такой блок первый раз вижу. Гуглил, не нашел там ничего особо. Как можно такое сверстать ?

Comment: Полно способов: 1. clip-path. 2. svg. 3. Просто поверх положить блок. 4. просто разные блоки.

Answer (score 3):

Да собственно наука не сложная

Открываем векторный редактор и обводим декоративные фигуры и группируем их это будет типа основы для нашего паттерна

Дальше ищем нужное изображение, я взял размер из головы 300х300 и получаем итоговый вариант

А дальше обычный html: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KjqMPg

> Если что то не ясно спрашивайте

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 900 900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp">
    <path d="M10,490 190,490 150,450 50,450 50,350 10,300z"/>
    <path d="M60, 440 490,440 490,210 440,160 440,60 380,60 280,10 60,10" />
    </clipPath>
 </defs>
   <image x="5" y="5" 
          width="490" 
          height="490" 
          clip-path="url(#cp)" 
          preserveAspectRatio="none"  
          xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogqRQ.jpg"/>
   <path d="M300,10  490,10 490,200  450,160 450,50 380,50z" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

И собственно всё

Comment: https://www.vectorizer.io/