# SVG маска не работает в Firefox

Tags: svg, mask

Один и тот же код работает в Chrome, но не работает в Firefox.

В чем может быть дело?

```css
svg{width:200px;height:300px}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="mask_circles">
           <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white">
               <circle cx="33%" cy="30%" r="20%" />
               <circle cx="52%" cy="62%" r="32%" />
            </g>
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#mask_circles)">
            <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/7/yoksel.4f/0_39955_f25b22ae_M" width="100%" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить неймспейс к svg

Comment: Увы не помогло :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё же наейспасе помог и размер изображения

```html
<svg width="199" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <defs>
        <mask id="circles">
              <g fill="#fff">
                 <circle cx="33%" cy="30%" r="20%"  stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
                 <circle cx="52%" cy="62%" r="32%"  stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
               </g> 
        </mask>
          
      </defs>
           <g mask="url(#circles)">
            <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/7/yoksel.4f/0_39955_f25b22ae_M" 
             width="199" 
             height="300"  />
           </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: а реально ли то же самое с path проделать ?
https://jsfiddle.net/dsovLefn/

Comment: @RickHangover  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997854/308951

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в маску  `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
       <defs>
       <mask id="mask_circles">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />   
        <g stroke="red" stroke-width="14">
               <circle cx="33%" cy="30%" r="20%" fill="white"/>
               <circle cx="52%" cy="62%" r="32%" fill="white" />
            </g>
        </mask>
       </defs> 
        <g mask="url(#mask_circles)">
            <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/7/yoksel.4f/0_39955_f25b22ae_M" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Странно, аналогичное решение с другим изображением работает:

Update

В первом примере добавлено `height="100%"` и всё заработало. Это невнимательность с моей стороны. Выражаю благодарность `@andreymal`и  `@MaximLensky`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 
  <mask id="msk1">
   <g fill="white">
   <!-- Left eye --> 
 <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
   <!-- Right eye -->
  <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
 </g> 
   </mask>
 
<g mask="url(#msk1)">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
</g>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Попробуйте проценты в маске заменить на пиксели и переделать своё приложение по примеру, как я привел. Оно работает в FF

Comment: я добился работоспособности в сафари, но еще не нажал опубликовать, там проблема в другом

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JQpQjP  всё работает просто он через задницу маску сделал

Comment: Работает только если в пикселях размеры задавать, а с процентами только в хроме почему-то

Comment: @RickHangover мой ответ посмотри там всё в твоих процентах

Comment: Так не работает, а если добавить `height="100%"`, то работает